# Semantic ui - Force update on progress bar

Tags: semantic-ui

**Situation (example):**
Script with 200 steps, each step takes ~5ms - ~10ms, increments progress bar (with *.progress('increment')*) at the end of each step.

**Problem:** The progress bar only updates one time at the end. I would like the update to be more consistent.

Below is the debug I get from the *Frequently Updated Progress* example. I can see that the progress bar is updated but in the example I give, I only get *Updated within interval* with a single progress bar update at the end.

[image]

Anyway I can "fix" this?

Thanks